# Probability: Determine independent event from isosceles triangle problem

Tags: probability

A point is selected at random from the triangle {(x,y):0 <=x <= y <=1}. Let E be the event that a selected point has the x coordinate is less than 0.5 and F be the event that y-coordinate is larger than 2 times the x-coordinate.

a) sketch event E and F in the triangle
b) Determine if E and F are independent.

What I did was event E is a trapezium and F is just the area above y=2 !Here's what I did but im not sure if Im right.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poymJ.jpg)

Comment: Event $E$ says that both coordinates $x, y$ are less than $0.5$, or only one of them?

Comment: only x coordinate, sorry for the typo

Comment: First of all, your triangle in diagram is incorrect, and I think your sketch of event $F$ is clearly wrong..

Comment: Should E and F be independent then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Event $E$ is determined by the line-inequality $x \leq 0.5$.

Event $F$ is determined by the line-inequality $y \geq 2x$.

To graph a line-inequality, graph the line and then shade everything to the left or right of the line, depending on the sign of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let our triangle be $T$.

$T=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x \leq y \leq 1\}$ is the portion of the unit square above(and left of) the line $x=y$

$E = \{(x,y)\in T\mid x < 0.5\}$ is the portion of $T$ to the left of the line $x=0.5$.

$F = \{(x,y)\in T\mid y > 2x \}$ is the portion of $T$ above the line $y=2x$, **not** the line $y=2$.

Comment: Thanks! Should E and F be not independent then ?